# Mapbox GL JS Listen for popup open event?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Is there any way to detect when a Mapbox popup gets opened? [This issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2584) in the mapbox repo describes a `close` event that works like this:

```
let popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
popup.on('close', function(e) {
    alert()
})
```

However, I can't find any way to detect when a popup opens. This does not work:

```
let popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
popup.on('open', function(e) {
    alert()
})
```

**EDIT:**

The popup event is now supported, so the example above should work.

Comment: close event fire twice when open and close.

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

While the official API does not provide a "open" event you could try to write your own custom event. See: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#evented#fire

```
 let popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
 popup.on('click', function(e) {
   // popup opened so we fire an event
   map.fire('your.custom.popup.event.name', {popup});
 });

 // subscribe to the event
 map.on('your.custom.popup.event.name', (popup) => { 
   console.log('do something with popup', popup);
 });
```

Comment: I ended up [adding the open event](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/commit/3c5cc10b4259b78f10481c8e9371608f84ae4072), so it is now supported. I forgot I had posted this question though.